# How to modify elements in React in scope of an instance of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So lets say I have 2 instances of a Component and there I have few buttons which take their data from server.

But the thing is these instances might use the same object, I might have this code:

```
<button id={object.id}>Button in component instance 1</button>
<button id={object.id}>Button in component instance 2</button>
```

So now comes my second misunderstanding and that is how can I change and modify these buttons in React, what is the React way to get the element and do something like `getAttribute`  ?

I might have function `<button onClick={deleteButton(1)}>Delete Button 1</button>` 
and the thing is I am not sure should I get the element by id or actually in some other way.

Below I uploaded a picture describing what confuses me.

[image: Some of the problems I can't figure out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each component, create *state* (which is separate for each instance) that indicates whether a button should be shown or not. For example, if the component is passed a number of the number of buttons to render, you could do something like:

```js
const ButtonList = ({ numButtons }) => {
  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = React.useState(() => (
    new Array(numButtons).fill(true)
  ));
  const hide = (changeIndex) => {
    setButtonState(buttonState.map(
      (orig, i) => i === changeIndex ? false : orig
    ));
  };
  return (
    buttonState.map((show, i) => !show ? null : (
      <div>
        <button>Button {i}</button>
        <button onClick={() => hide(i)}>Delete Button {i}</button>
      </div>
    ))
  );
};


const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ButtonList numButtons={1} />
    <ButtonList numButtons={3} />
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```